# What is a binary artifact?

Tags: devops, devops-services, devops-insights, gitlab-autodevops

I came across this term while looking for build automation in devops, I still am unsure about what exactly this term means.
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Artifacts** are usually the outcome of build processes: an output or collection of files (ex. JAR, WAR, DLL, RPM,.MD,YAML), and possibly metadata and documentation files as well.
In broader terms: Any process that is applied to a source code repository could yield an artifact.

A release is usually a collection of artifacts.

Artifacts can be stored- separately from source code(say, in Github)- in **artifact repositories**, or artifact/package management systems.  For example: *Sonatype Nexus*, and *Jfrog Artifactory*.

Comment: So basically nexus, maven repositories that store binaries are called artifact repositories, and something like GitHub could be called a source code repository ?

Comment: Basically, yes.